# Exclude nodes present in panel from view pane

Tags: views, panels

I have a panel page where a user selects nodes (using IPE) to be displayed, the page also contains a view pane, which must not contain those same nodes.

How do I get the view to exclude the nodes present in the panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue on a page with a lots of news and user customizable **Top News** - we used the module [views_exclude_previous](https://drupal.org/project/views_exclude_previous) module and it worked fine for this case.

Comment: I've added the views_exclude_previous filter to the view-pane which is added to the panel page. It seems to work well!